# How to determine larger probability of drawing one element from a set when set size and number of draws with replacement vary?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Which is the better scenario in terms of probability with the following:

**Scenario 1**

- I have a hat with 5 tickets in it (I have one).
- There is one single draw.
- I have a 20% chance that my ticket is drawn.

**Scenario 2**

- I have a hat with 25 tickets in it (I have one).
- There are 5 draws.
- After each draw the ticket is returned before the next draw. i.e. potential chance of being drawn 5 times.
- I have a 4% chance each draw

Which has the better probability of being drawn at least once? Ideally I'd like to know how to work this out (and why) so I can learn something :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is sometimes easier to work out the probability that an event *did not* occur rather than the probability that it did occur.  On each draw, the probability that your ticket is not drawn is $\frac{24}{25} = 0.96$, and thus the probability that your ticket is not drawn on all $5$ draws is $(0.96)^5$.  Thus,
the probability that your ticket is drawn *at least once* is just $1 - (0.96)^5$.  I will leave it to you to calculate the exact value and compare it to $0.20$.

Comment: could you explain why it does not work for (0.04)^5?

Comment: Thanks for your answer - are you able to label (narrow down) what type of problem/solution this is so I can read up about that theory?

Comment: @love-stats $(0.04)^5$ is the probability that the ticket held by the OP is drawn on all $5$ draws, and so if the question was "What is the probability that your ticket is _not_ drawn on at least one of the five draws?" the answer would be $1 - (0.04)^5$ which is _very close_ to $1$; it is _very highly_ likely that an event of probability $0.04$ will _not occur_ at least once on $5$ trials.

Comment: @PaulMason  This is fairly basic probability theory, usually covered in the first two or three chapters in most textbooks on _probability_; statistics textbooks are a different matter.  Look for "independent trials" and "sampling with replacement" on the Internet or in a probability textbook.  Schaum's Outline Series has a good book on probability with lots of worked examples.  Another one I would recommend is Carol Ash's A Probability Tutoring Book.